# How can i update a variable everytime i call it?

Tags: lua

For example, I have a variable that is a math, but I don't want to rewrite the equation all the time, but simply call the variable to do the math again.

How do I make it do the math again every time I call it? because even though x,y and z change their values throughout the script, math is returning the same value.

Or if there's another way of doing what I need.

```
   math = (x+y-z)

   print(math) -- same value

   -- some lines later

   print(math) -- same value again
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
math = function () return (x+y-z) end
print(math())
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way but to execute the assignment again to have math reflect the newer values of x, y and z.  If you want to explicitly avoid the *math = x(+y+z)*, try using *#define*

```
#define MATH_ADD (math=x+y+x) // This is not a neat way IMO though.
```

Comment: The question is about Lua, your answer uses the C preprocessor.

Comment: Sorry. didn't Notice the tag.

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are looking to do

```
float x;
float y
float z;

float math () {
    return x+y-z;
}
```

then when ever you call math it will return what ever you  have stored in x, y and z

Comment: question is about Lua not C